# cakephp auth and user register stopped working

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have following piece of code:

```
public function check()
        {
            $result = $this->User->field('id', array('username' => 'alek@lol.pl'));
            debug($result);
        }
```

In my users table I have record:

```
NSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `role`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES 
('5', 'alek@lol.pl', '64c918dd65b67b455248c2498bcc5421a66b68a6', 'member', '2012-04-24 10:56:37', '2012-04-24 10:56:37');
```

and the result of this controller method check is:

```
false
```

And the sql query is:

```
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   SELECT `User`.`id` FROM `freebooks`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `username` = 'alek@lol.pl' LIMIT 1      1   1   0
```

So SQL return one row but in cake result is 'false' - whats wrong? something broken??

when I execute this SQL statement in my PhpMyAdmin it correctly returns id = 5

And when I change one line to

```
$result = $this->User->find('all');
```

this prints

```
true
```

This is impossible!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->User->field('id', array('username', $this->request->data['User']['username']));
```

you can check like this:

```
if(!empty($this->User->field('id', array('username', $this->request->data['User']['username']));)) {

  // code
}
```

**OR**

```
$id = $this->User->field('id', array('username', $this->request->data['User']['username']));

$this->User->id = $id;

if($this->User->exists()) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: what is it and how it works??? When I execute MY code I even see cake sql info that this findByUser found 1 row! How is it possible?

Comment: @user606521 read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field

Comment: it's not working - it still returns 'false'! This is very strange - I can see MySQL query (provided by cake): 1 SELECT `User`.`id` FROM `freebooks`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `username` = 'alek@lol.pl' LIMIT 1     - num rows = 1 thats mean that it found this record - but it returns false...

Comment: @user606521 does it return the id

Comment: Ok - solved - it was my mistake - I had some afterFind in my Model which is not working good :)
Thanks